# kivy.Image not updating when ran from another thread in a while loop

Tags: python, kivy

I have two Kivy.Image objects in my class the main Image shows the main stream from webcam and the other shows the training samples being colllected from the main stream the process can done but we i run it at first before the were threads it blocked my application/ caused it to freeze then i introduced the threads it runs but it doesn't update the main stream and the one that shows training sample being collected.

I tried multiple ways of multi threading in python but it seems i can't figure it out

```
    from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    from kivy.app import App
    import threading

    import cv2
    from kivy.uix.image import Image
    from Clock_In import face as f
    class example(App):

        def build(self):

            layout = FloatLayout()
            self.user = Image()
            self.trainingSample = Image(source="C://Users//SELINA//Project Clock-in//data//Images//face_avatar.jpg")

            self.user.allow_stretch = True
            self.user.keep_ratio = True

            self.user.size_hint_x = 0.5
            self.user.size_hint_y = 0.9


            self.user.pos_hint = {"x":0.06, "y":0.2}

            self.trainingSample.allow_stretch =False
            self.trainingSample.keep_ratio = False

            self.trainingSample.size_hint_x = None
            self.trainingSample.size_hint_y = None

            self.trainingSample.width =160
            self.trainingSample.height=160

            self.face_Recognition = f.Recognition()
            self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
            self.trainingSample.pos_hint = {"x":0.6, "y": 0.68}
    self.btnText = Button(text="Collect Data", font_size=12, size_hint_y=None, size_hint_x=None, width = 150, height = 30, pos_hint= {"x":0.4, "y":0.6})
            self.btnText.bind(on_press=self.cdata)



            layout.add_widget(self.user)
            layout.add_widget(self.trainingSample)
            layout.add_widget(self.btnText)

            return layout
     #I have tried this
        def cdata(self, instance):
            threading.Thread(
              target=self.another, daemon=True
            ).start()

def another(self, dt):
    (self.im_width, self.im_height) = (160, 160)



    self.count = 0
    self.count_max = 10



    while self.count < self.count_max:

        ret = False

        while(not ret):
            (ret, frame) = self.capture.read()
            if(not ret):
                print("Couldn't run trying again")


                height, width, channels = frame.shape

                frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1, 0)
                normal = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                normal = cv2.cvtColor(normal, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

                if self.face_Recognition.identify(frame) is None:
                    faces = None


                if self.face_Recognition.identify(frame) is not None:
                    faces, points = self.face_Recognition.identify(frame)



                if faces is not None:
                    for face in faces:
                            face_bb = face.bounding_box.astype(int)
                            yourface = normal[max(0, face_bb[1]):min(face_bb[3], normal.shape[0]-1), max(0, face_bb[0]):min(face_bb[2], normal.shape[1]-1)]


                            face_resize = cv2.resize(yourface, (self.im_width, self.im_height))
                            cv2.rectangle(frame, (face_bb[0], face_bb[1]), (face_bb[2], face_bb[3]),(220,20,60), 1)
                            cv2.putText(frame, 'user', (face_bb[0], face_bb[3] + 20),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (220,20,60),1, cv2.LINE_AA)




                            print("Saving training sample " + str(self.count)+"/"+str(self.count_max))


                            cv2.imwrite('example' + str(self.count) + '.png', face_resize)

                            self.trainingSample.source = 'example' + str(self.count) + '.png'

                            self.count += 1

                    buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, 0)

                    buf = buf1.tostring()

                    texture1 = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
                    texture1.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')


                    self.user.texture = texture1





if __name__ == '__main__':
    example().run()
```

I want the self.user to update as the it taking user face Image and also the show the taken Image sample of the user in training sample Image in another thread in a while loop, i used david sandberg facenet from github, if you can please try using haarcascade or something simple the issue is not with the recognition but with kivy widgets updating to the user in real time as training sample are being collected

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc I tried implementing it above i wonder if you would have the time to implement facenet inorder to do face recognition

Comment: Don't use `Thread.run()`. That is not doing multi-threading. Use `Thread.start()`. And in your `coll()` method, use `Clock.schedule_once()` to call a simple method to set `self.user.texture`, which needs to be done back on the main thread.

Comment: @John Anderson i did what you told me to do, it breaks the gui completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your modified code still is not really using multi-threading, because your new `coll()` method simply schedules the `another()` method to run back on the main thread.

To actually use multi-threading, put the guts back into the `coll()` method, so that it is actually run in a new thread. And replace the `self.user.texture = texture1` with a `Clock.schedule_once()` call. Here is what I think it should look like (but I have not tested this code):

```
def cdata(self, instance):
    threading.Thread(
      target=self.coll, daemon=True).start()    

def coll(self):
    (self.im_width, self.im_height) = (160, 160)    
    self.count = 0
    self.count_max = 10  

    while self.count < self.count_max:    
        ret = False

        while(not ret):
            (ret, frame) = self.capture.read()
            if(not ret):
                print("Couldn't run trying again") 
                height, width, channels = frame.shape
                frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1, 0)
                normal = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                normal = cv2.cvtColor(normal, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

                if self.face_Recognition.identify(frame) is None:
                    faces = None
                if self.face_Recognition.identify(frame) is not None:
                    faces, points = self.face_Recognition.identify(frame)
                if faces is not None:
                    for face in faces:
                            face_bb = face.bounding_box.astype(int)
                            yourface = normal[max(0, face_bb[1]):min(face_bb[3], normal.shape[0]-1), max(0, face_bb[0]):min(face_bb[2], normal.shape[1]-1)]
                            face_resize = cv2.resize(yourface, (self.im_width, self.im_height))
                            cv2.rectangle(frame, (face_bb[0], face_bb[1]), (face_bb[2], face_bb[3]),(220,20,60), 1)
                            cv2.putText(frame, 'user', (face_bb[0], face_bb[3] + 20),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (220,20,60),1, cv2.LINE_AA)
                            print("Saving training sample " + str(self.count)+"/"+str(self.count_max))
                            cv2.imwrite('example' + str(self.count) + '.png', face_resize)    
                            self.trainingSample.source = 'example' + str(self.count) + '.png'    
                            self.count += 1    
                    buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, 0)    
                    buf = buf1.tostring()    
                    texture1 = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
                    texture1.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')  
                    #self.user.texture = texture1
                    Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.setUserTexture, texture1))

def setUserTexture(self, newTexture, dt)
    self.user.texture = newTexture
```

This is the picture showing the GUI

[image]

Comment: Well i did try your suggested edit as for  `self.user.texture`, it still doesn't change or update  in the GUI it just becomes black  but for the `self.trainingSample` Image object i did apply `Clock.schedule_once` to it, its now updating as samples are being taken.